# How to get random query?

Tags: 7, database

I use this code in my module for random query:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'client')
->fieldCondition('field_client_enabled', 'value', 1)
->addTag('random')
->range(0, 1)
->execute;
```

with additional function:

```
function mymodule_query_random_alter($query) {
  $query->orderRandom();
}
```

But why I get "undefined method" error when use

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'client')
->fieldCondition('field_client_enabled', 'value', 1)
->orderRandom() // why is this wrong?
->range(0, 1)
->execute;
```

?

Update:
**Answer**:
Found that orderRandom() is [SelectQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) function, but not [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7)

Can I simplify first code to variant without additional function?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I simplify first code to variant without additional function?

Not natively, as you've rightly said EFQ doesn't have a random order method. At a guess that's because field storage is pluggable, and it would be tricky to come up with a cross-compatible method that makes sense for e.g. MySQL and MongoDB. Might be wrong though, it may simply not have been considered important enough to implement/overlooked/etc.

If the extra step is unacceptable, the other option would be to subclass `EntityFieldQuery` to add your own random order method, and override the execute callback with your own version of [`field_sql_storage_field_storage_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!field_sql_storage!field_sql_storage.module/function/field_sql_storage_field_storage_query/7) to get it into the final query.

The method you already have is arguably a bit cleaner than that; certainly it's less effort.